# Add transition to Zoomable Circle Packing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this data in  `flare4.csv`:

```
SplitMth,id,value
Dec,FRUIT,
Dec,FRUIT~Apples,
Dec,FRUIT~Apples~X,100
Dec,FRUIT~Pears,
Dec,FRUIT~Pears~Y,200
Dec,FRUIT~Lemon,
Dec,FRUIT~Lemon~Z,300
Jan,FRUIT,
Jan,FRUIT~Apples,
Jan,FRUIT~Apples~X,300
Jan,FRUIT~Pears,
Jan,FRUIT~Pears~Y,200
Jan,FRUIT~Lemon,
Jan,FRUIT~Lemon~Z,100
```

I then have the following circle packing visualization , an adaptation of this `bl.ock`: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ZOOMABLE CIRCLE PACKING</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node:hover {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node--leaf {
        fill: white;
    }

    .label {
        font: 9px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-anchor: middle;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
    }

    .label,
    .node--root,
    .node--leaf {
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .clickBut {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 11px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
        background-color: #ffa500 !important;
        border-radius: 100px;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    #zoomable {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        left: 25px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="zoomable"></div>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Refresh|Reset" onclick="resetAll();" class="clickBut" />
    <select id="mth-menu"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var zoomableDataX = "flare4.csv";

    function resetAll() {
        console.log("resetAll pressed") //<< placeholder
    }

    populateMonthCombo();

    function populateMonthCombo() {
        removeOptions(document.getElementById("mth-menu"));

        d3.csv(zoomableDataX, function(rows) {

            //data for the combobox control
            dtaMths = rows.filter(function(row) {
                if ((1 === 1)) { //<< placeholder
                    return true;
                }
            }).map(function(d) {
                return {
                    "SplitMth": d.SplitMth
                };
            })

            var menu = d3.select("#mth-menu");

            menu.selectAll("option")
                .data(d3.map(dtaMths, function(d) {
                    return d.SplitMth;
                }).keys())
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .property("selected", function(d) {
                    return d === "Jan";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
                });

            menu
                .on("change", function() {
                    changeCircles(this.value)
                });

        });
    };

    function removeOptions(selectbox) {
        var i;
        for (i = selectbox.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectbox.remove(i);
        }
    };


    var zoomDiv = d3.select("#zoomable")

    var svg = zoomDiv.append("svg").attr("width", "250").attr("height", "250"),
        margin = 20,
        diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");


    //added>>>>>>
    var format = d3.format(",d");
    //>>>>>>>>>>>

    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([-1, 5])
        .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

    //added>>>>>>
    var stratify = d3.stratify()
        .parentId(function(d) {
            return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf("~"));
        });
    //>>>>>>>>>>>

    var pack = d3.pack()
        .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
        .padding(2);


    function changeCircles(mth) {
        console.log(mth);
        d3.csv(zoomableDataX, function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

            dta = data.filter(function(row) {
                if (row['SplitMth'] === mth) {
                    return true;
                }
            }).map(function(d) {
                return {
                    "id": d.id,
                    "value": +d.value,
                };
            })

            //added>>>>>>
            root = stratify(dta)
                .sum(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                })
                .sort(function(a, b) {
                    return b.value - a.value;
                });
            //>>>>>>>>>>>


            var focus = root,
                nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
                view;

            var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function(d) {
                    return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
                })
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;
                })
                .on("click", function(d) {
                    if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
                });


            var text = g.selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                    return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
                })
                .style("display", function(d) {
                    return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf("~") + 1).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g);
                })

            var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.id + "\n" + format(d.value);
                });

            svg
                .on("click", function() {
                    zoom(root);
                });

            zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

            function zoom(d) {
                var focus0 = focus;
                focus = d;

                var transition = d3.transition()
                    .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                    .tween("zoom", function(d) {
                        var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
                        return function(t) {
                            zoomTo(i(t));
                        };
                    });

                transition.selectAll("text")
                    .filter(function(d) {
                        return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline";
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                        return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0;
                    })
                    .on("start", function(d) {
                        if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline";
                    })
                    .on("end", function(d) {
                        if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none";
                    });

            }

            function zoomTo(v) {
                var k = diameter / v[2];
                view = v;
                node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
                });
                circle.attr("r", function(d) {
                    return d.r * k;
                });
            }

        })
    };

    changeCircles("Jan");
    </script>
</body>
```

When initially rendered it is as expected and will zoom in a predictable manner.
Live preview here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iPIsldJn09ZyLoc3GVrX?p=preview

I'd like to be able to do two things but I guess the second will need to be an additional question.

How do I amend the code so that when I select "Dec" from the input drop-down the visualization changes accordingly and behaves as expected when clicking to zoom?

(I'd like to make the above change a 5 second transition like this visual but that will be a second question : http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/WDCpq/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't handling the `update` and `exit` selections at all.  You are only handling the `enter`.   Here's some reading [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

Here's how to rewrite you drawing function the correct way:

```
function changeCircles(mth) {

  // Why download the file each time?

  dta = data.filter(function(row) {
    if (row['SplitMth'] === mth) {
      return true;
    }
  }).map(function(d) {
    return {
      "id": d.id,
      "value": +d.value,
    };
  })

  //added>>>>>>
  root = stratify(dta)
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
  //>>>>>>>>>>>


  var focus = root,
    nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
    view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes, function(d){
      return d.id; //<-- add a key function to uniquely identify a node
    });

  circle.exit().remove(); //<-- those nodes leaving

  circle = circle.enter() //<-- those nodes entering
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation();
    })
    .merge(circle); //<-- those entering and updating

 ...
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZokd86PNWvgqMbAOlQb?p=preview).

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar - thanks for help with this.

Comment: ...so I guess if (in the production code) one of the states has more data points I also need to add in an `exit.remove` step ?

Comment: @whytheq, yes.  Although I think I added that in my updated code.  Is it not working?

Comment: I can see the remove now: thanks. Did you try the zoom , unzoom etc? it does seem to behave a little strange - what do you think?

Comment: @whytheq, it was a little wonky.  I found the zoom code very confusing, with some scoping issues and strange variable assignment.  So I just cleaned it up a bit.  [Try it now](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZokd86PNWvgqMbAOlQb?p=preview)

Comment: thanks Mark - if I could up your answer further I would

Comment: just comparing to old code and you made lots of changes - thank you - (obviously) I'm new to js: one question - why below `//added>>>>>>` do you have `root = stratify(dta)...` rather than `var root = stratify(dta)...` ?

Comment: @whytheq, I did that to increase the scope (make root a global).  I was having trouble with the `svg.click` since root wouldn't be in scope if you only assigned it once (I thought the repeated assignment was messing up the zoom - it's wasn't).  In reality, I should have cleaned that up to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/whjaL64OL2JdZNqh7Wzi?p=preview